# Highstock legend flags

Tags: charts, flags, legend, highcharts

My flag data looks like this:

```
 events = [{"x":1116885600000,"title":"","name":"flag"}, {"x":1116738600000,"title":"","name":"flag"} ...]
```

Is it possible to show every element of my array "events" in the legend?
My legend only shows the the flag name:

```
type : 'flags',
data: events,
name: 'flag on series',
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

In legends, each item is serie, not points. So you need to prepare each point in separate series, then you achieve all points in legend.